# find non hidden directories

Tags: bash, terminal

i have this command

```
$ find -path './nas/cdn/catalog/[^.]*' -prune -type d
./nas/cdn/catalog/swatches
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length
./nas/cdn/catalog/cropped
./nas/cdn/catalog/drawings
```

but this does not return all the directories

```
$ find -path './nas/cdn/catalog/*' -type d
./nas/cdn/catalog/swatches
./nas/cdn/catalog/swatches/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res/back
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res/back/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res/front
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/high_res/front/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res/back
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res/back/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res/front
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/low_res/front/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/thumbs
./nas/cdn/catalog/product_shots/thumbs/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length/high_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/full_length/low_res
./nas/cdn/catalog/cropped
./nas/cdn/catalog/cropped/.AppleDouble
./nas/cdn/catalog/drawings
./nas/cdn/catalog/drawings/.AppleDouble
```

basically i want to remove all .AppleDouble and other .hidden directories from the find command

Comment: What did you expect `-prune` to do? It's preventing you from recursing into each found directory, as documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-regex` option:

```
find . -type d -regex '\./nas/cdn/catalog/[^.]*'
```

`[^.]*` pattern will make sure to not select any entry starting with DOT.